# How can I get log4net AdoNetAppender to insert NULL instead of "(null)" into my table?

Tags: log4net

Is there a way to get log4net to insert NULL into a database table using the AdoNetAppender and ODBC?  One similar question suggested using a CASE clause in the insert command, but I can't do that because I have to use ODBC, which doesn't support named parameters.  I am using ODBC because my application has to work with various types of databases, mainly SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

Comment: How about setting NullText Property as `null`: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Util_SystemInfo_NullText.htm

Comment: I'll try that.  Thank you.

Comment: Using null for the NullText property didn't work.  The database field got an empty string, not NULL.